# PHP compare doubt

Tags: php, operators, equality, comparison-operators

```
if(0 == ('Pictures'))
{
  echo 'true';
}
```

why it's giving me 'true' ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [PHP type comparison tables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to understand how comparison operators behave in PHP.

In your case, 'Pictures' becomes "0" and therefore 0 = 0.

Let's check following example:

```
echo (int)'Pictures'; // 0 => 'Picture' as int
echo 0 == 'Pictures'; // 1 => true, 0 = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Your string will be evaluated as an Integer, so becomes 0, use this : `0 === 'Pictures'` that verifies identity (same value and same type)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (0 === 'Pictures')
{
  echo 'true';
}
```

The `===` is strict type operator, it not only checks the value but the type as well.

**Quick Test:**

```
if(0 == 'Pictures')
{
  echo 'true';
}
else
{
  echo 'false';
}
```

outputs `true` but:

```
if(0 === 'Pictures')
{
  echo 'true';
}
else
{
  echo 'false';
}
```

outputs `false`